# LINUX/UNIX basic command questions

Tags: linux, unix

I'm trying to write a single command line that uses `netstat` and `grep` to count all connections in a state of “ESTABLISHED” and outputs a single number representing how many connections are currently open to the server.

```
netstat -an | grep ':portno'| grep ESTABLISHED| >> HOW DO I OUTPUT A SINGLE NUMBER?<<
```

Comment: netstat is deprecated, you should use `ss -s` for your purposes

Comment: What did you do to solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `wc -l` to the end of your command.

Answer (score 1):

`netstat` is deprecated, you should use `ss` for your purposes

use this command to get the number of established connections to port 80:

`ss -o state established '( sport = :http or sport = :https )' | wc -l`

For total number of connections use:

`ss -o state established  | wc -l`